# How to add space between sequential matplotlib figures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

How can I add space between multiple figures in the same Jupyter notebook cell in JupyterLab?
For clarity, I am not trying to add space between subplots but rather between figures.

For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
_ = plt.plot(x,y)

fig2 = plt.figure()
_ = plt.hist(z)
```

will have both figures 'attached' and I want to add space between them similar to how `print('\n')` adds space between printed outputs.

To further clarify, using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
_ = plt.plot([1, 2], [2, 3])

print('\n' * 4)

fig2 = plt.figure()
_ = plt.hist([1, 2, 3])
```

in JupyterLab leads to the new lines being placed in front of the plots, not between:

[image]

Comment: Just `print('\n')` should do the trick again.

Comment: @ddg, I already tried it. It doesn't.

Comment: try adding `plt.tight_layout()` https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-tight-layout-guide-py

Comment: @rzaratx, this will help with subplots. My goal is to add space between individual figures

Comment: huh it worked in my Jupyter

Comment: Please show a picture of where adding \n doesn't work

Comment: It does not work in JupyterLab. It is tagged appropriately but was not mentioned in the title nor text and this is probably the source of confusion.

Comment: My mistake. You're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a blank figure to create the space between figures:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
_ = plt.plot([1, 2], [2, 3])

f,ax = plt.subplots()
f.set_visible(False)
f.set_figheight(2) # figure height in inches

fig2 = plt.figure()
_ = plt.hist([1, 2, 3])
```

And control the spacing with `f.set_figheight()`

[To produce this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wuyl.png)

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to capture the plots in the ipywidgets' Output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

out1 = widgets.Output()
out2 = widgets.Output()
spacer = widgets.Output()

with out1:
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    _ = plt.plot([1, 2], [2, 3])
    plt.show()

with out2:
    fig2 = plt.figure()
    _ = plt.hist([1, 2, 3])
    plt.show()

with spacer:
    print('\n' * 4)

widgets.VBox([out1, spacer, out2])
```

Which results in:

[image: plots separated by four empty lines]

Comment: I was looking for a simpler and elegant method that utilizes matplotlib functionality.

Comment: I would be curious myself. Tried to help with the knowledge I have. The stateful API of matplotlib is weird and leads to issues like that and therefore I always avoid it preferring other libraries.